# How I can choose one from two checkmark?

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class UpdateUsersManagmentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func checkBoxTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        }) { (success) in
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                sender.transform = .identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }

}
}
```

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: need more description

Answer (score 0):

I would have a method that does that.

```
func toggleCheckmark(_ checkmark: UIButton) {
    if checkmark == self.checkmark1 {
        self.selectCheckmark1()
        self.deselectCheckmark2()
    } else if checkmark == self.checkmark2 {
        self.selectCheckmark2()
        self.deselectCheckmark1()
    }
}
```

Another option is something like this:

```
func toggleCheckmark(_ checkmark: UIButton) {
    self.selectCheckmark(self.checkmark1, on: checkmark == self.checkmark1)
    self.selectCheckmark(self.checkmark2, on: checkmark == self.checkmark2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select any of the one option from the group, it better to use radio buttons instead of check boxes.

If not, we should do it manually. I did it in swift and its working

```
@objc func selector(_ sender: NSButton)
{
    if sender == checkBox1
    {
        if sender.state == .on && checkBox2.state == .on
        {
            checkBox2.state = .off
        }
    }
    if sender == checkBox2
    {
        if sender.state == .on && checkBox1.state == .on
        {
            checkBox1.state = .off
        }
    }
}
```